# Why am I not able to assign the correct value of boolean result found in the program, to a boolean variable and to check a condition with the result?

Tags: java, android, validation, boolean, variable-assignment

I am receiving the value as true when log.d ing the logcat, but when I assign the value to boolean variable it changes to false and also I am not able to do the if condition with the value as it also is showing false. That is I am only able to get the value as true in log, don't know how to take the value to a variable or check some conditions. This code is used to validate a phone number:

```
Log.d("testi3", "id " + edit_number.getText());

    if (number.isEmpty()) {
        Log.d("testi3", "id empty" + edit_number.getText());
        edit_number.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.phone_error));
        isPhoneValid = false;
    } else {
        Log.d("testi3", "id else " + edit_number.getText());

        Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("[7-9][0-9]{9}");

        Matcher match = ptrn.matcher(number);

        Log.d("testi3", "id else 1 " + (match.find() && match.group().equals(number)));
        isPhoneValid = (match.find() && match.group().equals(number));
        Log.d("testi3", "id else validi" + isPhoneValid);

        if ((match.find() && match.group().equals(number))) {
            Log.d("testi3", "id else 2 " + (match.find() && match.group().equals(number)));
            isPhoneValid = true;
        } else {
            Log.d("testi3", "id else 3 " + (match.find() && match.group().equals(number)));
            edit_number.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.phone_error));
            isPhoneValid = false;
        }
    }
```

This is the logcat on entering a number as input:

```
D/testi3: id 9048857563
D/testi3: id else 9048857563
D/testi3: id else 1 true
D/testi3: id else validi false
D/testi3: id else 3 false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [matcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Matcher) is created from a pattern by invoking the pattern's matcher method. Once created, a matcher can be used to perform three different kinds of match operations:

- The [matches](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Matcher#matches()) method attempts to match the entire input sequence
  against the pattern.
- The [lookingAt](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Matcher#lookingAt()) method attempts to match the input sequence, starting
  at the beginning, against the pattern.
- The [find](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Matcher#find()) method scans the input sequence looking for the next
  subsequence that matches the pattern.

Each of these methods returns a boolean indicating success or failure. More information about a successful match can be obtained by querying the state of the matcher.

**Matches** - Attempts to match the entire region against the pattern.
If the match succeeds then more information can be obtained via the start, end, and group methods.
In your scenario , when you first time matches the patter using `(match.find() && match.group().equals(number)))` - match is found success and values in the `matcher` are updated, to be more specific `matchFound` and `group` value is updated. Next time comparing the values using same matcher group doesn't satisfy the condition and hence result in false.

You can use `match.matches()` to check if match is success or not for next use of match instead of comparing again.
**Or** you can reset the matcher using [`reset()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Matcher#reset()) method

Comment: You can also debug your code to verify the same, you will see the values change after the first success match.